# Shouldn't these ks the other way round in this C program?

Tags: c, matrix

I wanted to make a program in C that multiplies two matrices. I'll show now how I did it. However, my teacher told me it was wrong and showed me the right way of doing it which doesn't make sense to me.
This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 2
#define P 3
#define N 2
int main()
{
int a[M][P],b[P][N],c[M][N];
int i,j,k;
/* here is where we fill the matrices */
for (i=0;i<M;i++)
for (j=0;j<N;j++)
{
c[i][j]=0;
for (k=0;k<P;k++)
c[i][j]+=a[k][j]*b[i][k];
}
}
```

And this is what my teacher said:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 2
#define P 3
#define N 2
int main()
{
int a[M][P],b[P][N],c[M][N];
int i,j,k;
/* here is where we fill the matrices */
for (i=0;i<M;i++)
for (j=0;j<N;j++)
{
c[i][j]=0;
for (k=0;k<P;k++)
c[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j]; /*Here there is the difference, instead of a[k][i]*b[j][k], it's a[i][k]*b[k][j]*/
}
}
```

But it doesn't make sense to me because when you multiply matrices, the process you do goes like this:

[image]

So, you go from left to right in Matrix A and from top to bottom in Matrix B (for example: ae+bg). Therefore, it makes sense to write c[i][j] += a[k][j]*b[i][k] in the for loop because k increases by 1 for each iteration.

Do you understand what I mean? Do you think I'm wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In C dimensions are index from left to right, which is exactly the other way round as in (hand) written math.

Comment: Which version produces the correct answer?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield The second one!

Comment: @alk I'm sorry. I don't understand it. Could you please tell me an example?

Comment: Here's an easy check: in your last loop, `k` ranges from `0` to `P-1`.  You use it as the first subscript of `a[k][j]`, but `a` is declared as `a[M][P]`.  So if P > M, you index out of bounds in the first subscript.  I think you were perhaps expecting an interpretation of the subscripts as `[cols][rows]` while the instructor clearly intended `[rows][cols]`.  (FWIW, it looks like yours is a correct implementation for `[cols][rows]` but the dimensions given the declaration of `a` and `b` are only compatible with the `[rows][cols]` interpretation.

Comment: They are both bad, since `c[i][j]+=` is adding to elements of the *uninitialised* array `int c[M][N];`

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, sorry. I've just edited it.

Comment: ... and presumably the code comment `/* here is where we fill the matrices */` is a substitute for providing input data.

Comment: Well, if your version doesn't produce the correct answer, and you teacher's version does produce the correct answer, then you can answer your own question: "Do you think you're wrong?"

Comment: @MarkBenningfield teachers are often wrong.  I proctored an exam where the prof asked a question about the evaluation order of arguments in C89.  When I pointed out the error the reply was "well, I taught them left-to-right, so they know how to answer"... : |.  In the OP's case the instructor should've made M distinct from N, so that the intended indexing scheme for the matrix was more obvious.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b: Far be it from me to assert that teachers are never wrong. However, in this case, the teacher's implementation is correct. The OP failed to grasp that multi-dim arrays in C are in 'row-major' order.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield that's true, but there's no requirement that the "matrix row" equate to the "array row".  I have had occasion to write several column-major matrix utilities in C's row-major array structure (e.g., where there were a lot of column-extraction operations I wanted to perform with a single memcpy).  I agree that the instructors intent was clear here by the use of M,N, and P in the array sizes, but if those had been dynamically read, then the OPs solution is an equally valid interpretation of the problem.  He should probably seek partial credit if nothing else.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b: Well, now we begin to venture on information that we don't possess.